# Drawing an OpenGL overlay using SwapBuffers interception

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I'm trying to make a library that would allow me to draw my overlay on top of the content of a game window that uses OpenGL by intercepting the call to the SwapBuffers function. For interception i use Microsoft Detours.

```
BOOL WINAPI __SwapBuffers(HDC hDC)
{
    HGLRC oldContext = wglGetCurrentContext();

    if (!context) // Global variable
    {
        context = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    }

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, context);

    // Drawing

    glRectf(0.1F, 0.5F, 0.2F, 0.6F);

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, oldContext);

    return _SwapBuffers(hDC); // Call the original SwapBuffers
}
```

This code works, but occasionally, when I move my mouse, my overlay blinks. Why? Some forums have said that such an implementation can significantly reduce FPS. Is there any better alternative? How do I correctly translate a normal position to an OpenGL position? For example, width = 1366. It turns out 1366 = 1, and 0 = -1. How to get the value for example for 738? What about height?

Comment: `ndc_x = 2.0 * window_x / 1366.0 - 1.0` - NDC (Normalized Device Coordinate)

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate issue, `__SwapBuffers` is a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) ("identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved").

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know. Well, it kind of works with this.. I just don't know how best to name the real SwapBuffers and my SwapBuffers functions.

Answer (score 0):

To translate a screen coordinate to normal coordinate you need to know the screen width and screen height, linear mapping from [0, screenwidth] to [-1, 1] / [0, screenheight] to [-1, 1]. It is as simple as follows:

```
int screenwidth, screenheight;
//...
screenwidth = 1366;
screenheight = 738;
//...
float screenx, screeny;
float x = (screenx/(float)screenwidth)*2-1;
float y = (screeny/(float)screenheight)*2-1;
```

Problem z=0:
`glRect` renders to z=0, it is a problem because the plane would be infinitely near. Because opengl considers rendering to world space still. Screen space lies at (x, y, 1) in non transformed world space. OpenGL almost always works with 3D coordinates.

There are two ways to tackle this problem:

1. You should prefer using functions with a z component, because opengl does not render correctly at z=0. z=1 corresponds to the normalized screen space
2. or you add a `glTranslatef(0,0,1);` to get to the normalized screen space

Remember to disable depth testing when rendering 2D on the screen space and resetting the modelview matrix.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what exactly I need to do. After wglMakeCurrent (hDC, context); I am setting glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); and draw a rectangle with glVertex3f (0.0, 0.5, 1); but it still flickers :(